# NSMutableArray Programmatically?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to allow the user to have multiple groups of data all in NSMutableArrays. I don't want to have to limit the amount of arrays they can create but I don't see how one could make multiple arrays with different names so they don't keep overwriting the same data. For example:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

and

```
-(IBAction)createNewArray {
[array addObject:first.text];
[array addObject:second.text];
[array addObject:third.text];
[array addObject:fourth.text];
//Add this set of data to a larger group which is all the arrays
[allArrays addObject:array];

}
```

The problem is that it would keep adding different data with the same name which would become useless because 1. I believe it would keep overwriting the same object and 2. There's no way to differentiate the objects.

My question: Is there any possible way to create multiple arrays with different names without having to put them in the .h first?

Comment: sounds like you want an association between a user generated **key** and a user generated **array**. You should look at `NSDictionary`. I recommend reading some programming books!

Comment: The contents of an array aren't named, they're indexed. Right now, the first array you add to allArray would be `0`, the second would be `1`, the third `2`, and so on. If you want them to be *named*, you'd use a `NSMutableDictionary` (as nielsbot said). But then you have the problem of coming up with unique names for each item.

Comment: An `init...` method should only be called once in the lifetime of a given object. Your example is sending an `init` message to the object stored in the local variable `array` and then sending `initWithObjects:` to the same object on the next line. The result should be a compiler warning and a runtime crash. You might want to update the code in your question to follow the call to `alloc` immediately with a call to `initWithObjects:`.

Answer (score 1):

A NSDictionary of NSMutableArrays

Comment: How would you be able to create a new NSMutableArray from within a NSDictionary because from my understanding I thought NSDictionary just assigns text/keys to objects which solves half of the problem

Comment: no, dictonary is key to value; value is the NSMutableArray, key whatever you like tonidentify your array

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wan't to worry about name collisions you can use an array of arrays,

Alternatively - If you want to generate unique names without collisions - have a try:

```
NSString *uniqueName = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```